# Eclipse C++ undefined reference

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, modbus

I am trying to use `libmodbus` and i have the following :

```
extern "C" {
#include "modbus.h"
#include "modbus-tcp.h"
}

void executeMbus() {
    modbus_t *mb;
    uint16_t tab_reg[32];
    mb = modbus_new_tcp("127.0.0.1", 1502);
    modbus_connect(mb);

    /* Read 5 registers from the address 0 */
    modbus_read_registers(mb, 0, 5, tab_reg);

    modbus_close(mb);
    modbus_free(mb);
}
```

I have added the path to the library in `C/C++ General ->  Paths and Symbols GNU C++` and i added the path to the modbus lib.
However i'm getting weird undefined reference for each `modbus_` method.
How can i fix it ?

Comment: What's the actual command line invoking the compiler? My guess is you failed to add the library objects to the object to link, only provided the search path for it.

Comment: @YSC   i586-poky-linux-g++ -lmraa -fno-use-linker-plugin "--sysroot=C:\\Users\\hdta\\workspace\\libs\\iot2000-sdk-windows-2.1.2.tar\\iot2000-sdk-windows-2.1.2/sysroots/i586-nlp-32-poky-linux" -o Iot2020WithMB example.o 
example.o: In function `executeMbus()':     after that i just get undefined reference to all modbus_ methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 2):

For the library libmodus to be linked with your program, you need to:

1. Add the include path to the compiler settings `C/C++ general -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes -> GNU C++`
2. Add the library path to the linker settings `C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Library Paths`
3. Add the library object to the linker settings `C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries` [image: screenshot]

You did (1.) and (2.) but you also need to do (3.).

Comment: thanks for your input sir. One small problem is that in my case i use IOT2000 C++ Compiler , so i dont have the option to add libraries to the Linker(there is just General tab there). I guess i need to make another just C++ project

Comment: @ChrisTanev if your compiler is not known by Eclipse, it should provide you with the ability to provide custom command line arguments. What does the "General" tab look like?